# Border top and bottom is acting strange

Tags: html, css

I want to make a border around a whole element not just around the actual text of the element:

> CSS

```
.boxcontent .box1 .post-content p .intro {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #b1b1b1;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  borter-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

> HTML

```
<div class="post-content">
  <p>
    <span>...</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

[Screenshot of Above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8zwm.jpg)

[image: Thats how my code is acting]

And I want my border to be all over that text, i mean i want to cut those borders from the middle.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, I converted one of your images to the bit of the code that you are talking about and the other to an embedded image.  Take a look at the comment from Paulie_D and edit your question to be clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The borders are acting according to how inline elements are to be treated, which is what your `.intro` element is. If you want just one border around everything, convert it to a block-level element.

Add `display: block;` to your `.intro` definition.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve, but I think [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZkH2.png) is what you are after?

Instead of applying the the `border-top` and `border-bottom` to your `<span class="intro">`, just apply it to the `<p>` tag like so:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wddJC.png)

```
<html>
<style>
    p {
        border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
</style>
<p><span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</span></p>
```